# Control 12V motor from 3.3V GPIO with external 12V Power Supply

Tags: gpio, power, switches, voltage, dc-motor

I have a 12V motor, which I need to control from my Raspberry Pi (through the RaspiRobot Board). However, the RaspiRobot Board gives me only 3.3V for the motor. 
At the same time, I have a 12V adapter  (that came with the motor).

What I now require is, that I power the Motor from the 12V Adapter, and Switch it On/Off from the RaspiRobot Board (with the 3.3V output).

The RaspiRobot Board also lets me Switch the polarity, so it would be better if I could control the direction of the motor in this way too.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know the capabilities of the RaspiRobot board. You need to edit the question and include far more information if you want help.

Comment: @joan As in this, the capability of the RaspiRobot Board is just supplying  (or not supplying) 3.3V, and change the polarity of the supply.

Comment: Seems a waste of money if that is all it does.  I repeat you need to edit the question and include any relevant information.

Comment: It seems you need a *hardware interface* to make this work. A hardware interface is simply some switches (transistors or relays) that take the 3.3V signals from your RPi as *control inputs*. These control inputs cause the hardware interface to  turn a 12V switch ON or OFF - or FORWARD, REVERSE and STOP as the case may be. But @joan is correct - we can't help you with the information you've provided so far.

Comment: I don't know about the RaspiRobot board, but the spec says it has to be powered by a 6V-12V supply and I suppose its output equals to input. As a generic solution for 12V motors I can recommend the L298N Dual Full H-Bridge (4 mosfet in a single package), which is specially designed for driving DC motors (forward, reverse, stop) - probably the RaspiRobot board is based on same principle.

Comment: @Seamus I believe that is what I exactly require. Could you kindly elaborate on this? And the RaspiRobot Board is actually made just to make it easier for one to create a robot car - with a supporting python library. It's working is actually really simple, and we don't really need it to do what it does.

Comment: @ijavid You are right, thats the limit for the power supply. However the output is fixed at 3.3V

Comment: @joan Btw, I got this board as a gift. It however, works are a motor driver.

Comment: @MrigankPawagi I don't think so, the RaspiRobot board provides full voltage from the connected battery pack. You should power your system via battery pack connected to RaspiRobot board (not from RPi usb port) The offical docs says: "The RRB3 provides power to the motors direct from the battery pack." Check the corresponding section here: https://www.monkmakes.com/rrb3/
Use a multimeter and measure voltage on the motor screw terminals.

Comment: @ijavid Yes, I read Something similar from the Raspberry Pi Forum. Thanks a lot.